# Find absolute difference between 2 columns with dates of different formats as number of days

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I need to find the absolute difference in days between 2 columns which have dates in python.
This is pretty easy in excel but I want in python.

I have a xlsx file which I have read to a python dataframe(using `pd.read_excel`) with sample data reading as below:
The columns have the date details in the plain text format of ddmmyyyy/dmmyyyy.

**A                   B**
1102012
26071993        27122007
28062010        3122015
16012010        21022016
02082015        14092010

Now I need to create a new column C which contains the absolute number of days difference between A and B. A can be less than or greater than B.
If B is empty then it should consider current date for days calculation. But A will not have empty/NULL values.

So output will be the difference of number of days:

**C**
2432
5267
1984
2227
1783

The approach I followed was:

1. Convert A and B to 8 digits as we have only 7 digits in some values of A and B - using `df['A'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>8}'.format(x))`
2. Convert A to datetime field using `pd.to_datetime`
3. Create another temporary column say CC by copying B values and with all not NULL date values(that is replacing NULL/empty with current date)
4. Then find the absolute difference between A and CC(number of days)

I am stuck in third step and not able to proceed. Is there any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First fomratting options is a good idea. Avoids confusion as to which is day or month.

```
# Recreate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([["1102012", pd.np.NaN],["26071993","27122007"],
                   ["28062010","3122015"],["16012010","21022016"],
                   ["02082015","14092010"]], columns=["A","B"]) 
print(df)
>>>
          A         B
0   1102012       NaN
1  26071993  27122007
2  28062010   3122015
3  16012010  21022016
4  02082015  14092010

print(df.dtypes)
>>>
A    object
B    object
dtype: object
```

So the dataframe we are working from is above. The data types are all `object` (string). Would be good if you can confirm this step as everything else stems from here.

```
# convert some datetimes
# Assumption is that column A is not sparse - there are no NaNs
# Column B can be NaN so make it today if so
m = df["B"].isnull()
df.loc[m, "B"] = pd.datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y") 
print(df)
>>>
          A         B
0   1102012  03062019
1  26071993  27122007
2  28062010   3122015
3  16012010  21022016
4  02082015  14092010

# now we zero pad some numbers
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>8}'.format(x))
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>8}'.format(x))
print(df)
>>>
          A         B
0  01102012  03062019
1  26071993  27122007
2  28062010  03122015
3  16012010  21022016
4  02082015  14092010
```

Then use to_datetime:

```
df["A"] = pd.to_datetime(df["A"], format="%d%m%Y")
df["B"] = pd.to_datetime(df["B"], format="%d%m%Y")
print(df)
>>>
           A          B
0 2012-10-01 2019-06-03
1 1993-07-26 2007-12-27
2 2010-06-28 2015-12-03
3 2010-01-16 2016-02-21
4 2015-08-02 2010-09-14

print(df.dtypes)
>>>
A    datetime64[ns]
B    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Then the diff

```
df["Diff"] = (df["A"] - df["B"]).abs()
print(df)
>>>
           A          B      Diff
0 2012-10-01 2019-06-03 2436 days
1 1993-07-26 2007-12-27 5267 days
2 2010-06-28 2015-12-03 1984 days
3 2010-01-16 2016-02-21 2227 days
4 2015-08-02 2010-09-14 1783 days

# or
df["Diff"] = (df["A"] - df["B"]).abs().dt.days
print(df)
>>>
           A          B  Diff
0 2012-10-01 2019-06-03  2436
1 1993-07-26 2007-12-27  5267
2 2010-06-28 2015-12-03  1984
3 2010-01-16 2016-02-21  2227
4 2015-08-02 2010-09-14  1783
```

Comment: After formatting B, in second step while using to_datetime only throws error:   Running the command `df["B"] = pd.to_datetime(df["B"], format="%d%m%Y")` throws `ValueError: time data '00000nan' does not match format '%d%m%Y' (match)`.

Comment: @ggg_datascience so you've got NaNs and not blank strings?

Comment: The blanks are represented as NaNs which gets appended with 00000 when we do formatting.

Comment: not anymore. I ammended to place current date into blanks first (as originally requested)

Comment: Thanks Will for your response. When I run the second step to_datetime for B it returned error as `ValueError: unconverted data remains: .0`. When I tried to find out the data types, for A it is int64 but B is float64, hence throwing this error. I tried converting B to int using `df['B'] = df['B'].astype('int64')` but it throws `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '27122017.0'`. Can you pls help here.

Comment: @ggg_datascience wow, we really do have mixed up datatypes between us. I'll have another look

Comment: I've edited answer again to show my outputs at every step. The answer is 100% reproducible so if you have different outputs then either your input data does not look like that in the question or the steps are being copied funny

Comment: Thanks again Will. My data types from step 1 is: A as `int64` and B as `float64`. I think having B as `float64` is causing the issue.

Comment: @ggg_datascience ok so when you read the xlsx file initially, set your data conversion rules to ensure you read those columns as strings otherwise pandas will convert them for you.

Comment: Thanks much Will. I tried converting them to int(to be in same data type as A) while reading from excel and it worked fine. Results were as expected. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: *explain on error*

As you said the error in comment. It means your column `A` is not dtype `object`. It is either `int32` or `int64`. Run this command to confirm (*I changed sample data column `A` dtype to demonstrate the error*):

```
df.dtypes

Out[2866]:
A     int32
B    object
dtype: object
```

Before using `str.zfill`, you need to change your `df` to `object` as follows:

```
df = df.astype(str)

Out[2870]:
A    object
B    object
dtype: object
```

After converting dtype to `object`, everything will works.

---

`zfill(8)` to pad 0 to strings and convert them to datetime using `pd.to_datetime` with `coerce`, and `filna` on `NaT` with today date. Next, do subtraction `A` and `B`, make `abs` and get `days` from `timedelta`

*Note*: adding pre-process to convert `df` dtype to `object` using `astype(str)`

```
df = df.astype(str) 
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.str.zfill(8), format='%d%m%Y', errors='coerce')).fillna(pd.datetime.today().date())
df1.A.sub(df1.B).abs().dt.days

Out[2599]:
0    2432
1    5267
2    1984
3    2227
4    1783
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Running the first line, throws attribute error: `AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index A')`.

Comment: @ggg_datascience: it means your real data column `A` is not `dtype object`. It is probably dtypes `int32` or `int64`.  You need to use `astype(str)` to convert `df` to `dtype object`. Check my update

Comment: Thanks Andy for your response. It came pretty close - I was able to get the results. But results are not correct for not NULL values of 'B'. Eg: diff of 26071993, 27122007.0 is giving 9443. When I tried to find out the data types, for A it is `int64` but B is `float64`. I think due to this it is not showing correct results. Can you pls help me here.

Comment: I tried removing .0 using `str.replace('\.0', '')` and the difference came out fine. Thanks again Andy!